# Reimport changed library from

Tags: python

In my project I have a directory (./Mylibs) with all my own libraries.
To import them I simply write:

```
from Mylibs import configure, db, logger
```

This works fine. But during the execution I need to change something in the configure.py library and need this changes reimported. Therefor I did:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(configure)
```

But this didn't work and I can't use the changes in my code.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I read that you have to reconstruct the objects after the reload. Are you doing this?

Comment: I think you should redefine your import `configure = importlib.reload(configure)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: for reloading configuration, maybe easier to use e.g. json loading. python module reload is for code, and indeed requires you take care to recreate the objects.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Yes, that didn't work. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'configure' referenced before assignment`